# So confused. Where to edit ACCOUNT / CART

Tags: magento-1.9

I checked .csv files under languages folder. Couldn't find where to change this section(**EDIT THE TEXT**):
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: what you actually want to do??Remove them or change just the names??

Comment: what you want to do

Comment: I want to edit the text. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not defined anywhere, so it just stays as 'Cart' unless you have it added to your translate.csv file or any other .csv that is loaded.

It looks like you're using the defauklt rwd theme, so if you open 
`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv` and add the following on a new line:

```
"Cart", "Shoppingcart"
```

It should translate it to 'Shoppingcart'

Comment: Theres only etc, layout and template directories.

Comment: Then look inside the `app/etc/locale/en_US/XXXXXXX.csv` files

Comment: then create folders locale/en_US and add a text file with that single line and call it translate.csv in locale/en_US. Or you could enable inline translations in admin->configuration->advanced->developer and browser the front end to translate the word/phrase

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Which language are you using? Obviously `en_US` is american english, if you use a different locale your folder should be called appropriately.

Comment: I checked my local language folders aswell. I created the file but it had no effect whatsoever, even after clearing cache.